# How do you retrieve the URL for authentication in R's httr::oauth2.0_token?

Tags: r, oauth-2.0, access-token, httr

I use the code below to get API access to my Microsoft Dynamics Environment where data is stored.

```
require(httr)

dataverse_api = oauth_endpoint(request = NULL, 
  authorize = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[REDACTED]/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
  access = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[REDACTED]/oauth2/v2.0/token",
  base_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://[REDACTED].crm4.dynamics.com")

API.Key = "[REDACTED]"
API.Secret = "[REDACTED]"

App = oauth_app("[REDACTED]", key = API.Key, secret = API.Secret)

API.token = oauth2.0_token(dataverse_api, App, scope = "https://[REDACTED].crm4.dynamics.com/user_impersonation", cache = FALSE, use_oob = FALSE)

API.AuthKey = API.token$credentials$access_token
```

If I run the code in RStudio, it points my browser to a URL and I get the response:

```
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Authentication complete
```

However, if I run the code in the R Terminal, it returns the URL into the R Terminal that I then need to copy and paste into the browser to complete the authentication.

What I want to know is... what is RStudio doing to automate this step? **How does RStudio know the URL to open? How can I extract that URL and put it into a browseURL function to automate this last step?** Here is what I've tried...

- I've looked through all of the parameters of my API.token by typing `API.token$` and continuing down the path to explore things like `cache_path`, `private_key`, `endpoint$authorize`, `params$...`. In all of these parameters I haven't found anything that matches the URL that gets opened in my web browser from RStudio.
- I've tried setting `use_oob=TRUE`, but this actually provides a 400-type response.
- I've looked through `?oauth2.0_token` and the link to `Token()` provided in the Details section, which I didn't find helpful.

I'm expecting that somewhere there is a parameter that I can extract and put it into a code like this:

```
browseURL(paste("http://localhost:1410/?code=","INSERT PARAMETER HERE",sep = ""))
```

Does anyone know how to get that parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant code is at the bottom of [oauth-init.R](https://github.com/r-lib/httr/blob/main/R/oauth-init.R). But like a lot in {httr} it is complicated.

The docs of [{AzureAuth}](https://github.com/cloudyr/AzureAuth) are clearer. If you're in RStudio both packages are using the [**authorization_code**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) flow and use a small {httpuv} web server to catch the redirect. You can see the required request [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) on the help page. Here is the request URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri={http://where-you-listen-for-the-response.might-be-localhost escaped for use in URLs}
&response_mode=query
&scope={scope escaped for use in URLs}
&state=12345
```

If you open the above in a browser, Azure will sign you in for the app specified in `client_id` with the `scope`s in the request and then redirect you to `redirect_uri` with a code. **If you have a web server running on `redirect_uri`** (that's where the httpuv comes in) and if the `redirect_uri` is whitelisted for that Azure App, your R program receives that code and can then use it to acquire an access token from the token endpoint.

This constructs the URL. You need something to manage the `state`s.

```
url <-
    httr::modify_url(
       endpoint_authorize,
       query = list(client_id = client_id,
                    response_type = "code",
                    redirect_uri = redirect_uri,
                    scope = scope,
                    response_mode = "query",
                    state = get_state_key())
    ) %>%
    htmltools::HTML()
```

From the terminal it uses the **device_code** auth flow that does not need a redirect. Instead you act as your own "network link" by copying the code into the browser.

Depending on your use case those two authorization flows might be overkill. It is meant as a way for a server to securely acquire a token that allows it to access resources in your name. If you're only getting a token for your local machine and you have control over what flows the app accepts (because it is your own), that can generally be handled by the **client_credentials** flow.

If you look at the above-mentioned [{AzureAuth}](https://github.com/cloudyr/AzureAuth) you can see the alternatives. Googling for "Azure" and the names of the flows will lead you to the docs on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL building capabilities of the `httr` in which you can add your parameters

```
httr::GET(
  url = "https://geo.stat.fi/geoserver/vaestoalue/wfs",
  query = list(
    code = "INSERT PARAMETER HERE",
    param2 = "INSERT PARAMETER2 HERE"
  )
) -> res
```

Comment: I don't follow... can you show me how that relates to my code or where it would go in my code? I don't know what the parameters are; that's the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Can you tell me what URLs are you wanting to form? Give some examples

Comment: I can't. That's the crux of the problem. RStudio seems to know the URL I need to point my browser to, but I do not know how to find or generate it myself.